# Server side Exception or error to be propagated to JSP in Spring

Tags: spring, exception

I am trying to show an custom error message on any occurrence of exception or error in my business layer. I am catching the exception in my controller and I would like to display it in my JSP.

This exception or error is not associated with any field in the screen, it's a pure server exception. I am also using an Annotated Controller. I am using Prototype for making AJAX requests to my controller.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring you can register a `HandlerExceptionResolver` which will catch exceptions thrown by your Spring MVC controllers and forward them to the view layer for rendering. These are described in the Spring docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers). Start with the `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` (see [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html)) which gives a simple mechanism for mapping exception types to views.

However, if the exception occurs outside if your Spring controller, for whatever reason, then you'll need a more generic fall-back solution, which involves configuring error pages in your `web.xml` file. This is not Spring-specific. See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.servlet.http/webxmlerrorpagewithexceptiontype.htm) for an example of how to do it.

Comment: Hi Skaffman,

 I am sorry not to have mentioned the version of Spring I am using. I am using version 2.5 and I was looking at some annotation based alternatives. Thanks for the great answer.

Cheers,J

Comment: @jadaaih: Not an option in Spring 2.5, I'm afraid. You'll need to use XML config in either Spring or web.xml